# HTTP Web Request is sending twice (How to fix?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got the following code to perform a web request and fetch HTTP response. What I'm trying to do is, IF HTTP Response is

> 200 OK

I need to read the response body without sending the web request again (I know my code is currently sending it twice).

```
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        string result = webClient.DownloadString(request.RequestUri);
                        if(result.StartsWith("NUMBER NOT IN LIST"))
                        {
                            return "Number Not In List";
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                else if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    return statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString();
                }
                else if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    return statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.ToString();
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the response stream:

```
    try
    {
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if(result.StartsWith("NUMBER NOT IN LIST"))
                {
                    return "Number Not In List";
                }
                return result;
            }
            else if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                return statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString();
            }
            else if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                return statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream as seen here:

[HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx)

Replace the contents of your `if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)` using the example on the MSDN page.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  // we will read data via the response stream
  var resStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
  var sr = new StreamReader(resStream);
  var result = sr.ReadToEnd();

}
```